# Swat attack aside

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Swat your attack aside" in the following sentence?

> The Yak swats your attack aside and counter-attacks, crashing into you like a battering ram!

Is it like Ignore your attack or slap your attack away?

I looked up the word in the dictionary, it said, To strike or hit with a sharp blow or To strike or try to strike something with a sharp blow. But the both are talking about the actual things and attack is not like a ball or mosquito.

Answer (score 2):

To **swat *at*** something means to *attempt* to hit it with your hand or with something else like a baseball bat or a rolled up newspaper or a "fly swatter". You swat at things you would like to go away, wishing that *they* would ignore *you*. When you're swatting at things, you're not ignoring them. They're bothering you.

To **swat** something ***aside*** means to make quick and forceful contact with it (using your hand and forearm,  or some other thing acting as an extension of your arm) in a way that causes it to move sideways from its former path (or flattens it, if it is small like a fly).

A bear or tiger could swat at something with a forepaw.  A strike with the hind paws would not typically be called a "swat". It's the same with humans: we swat with our hands (or a thing our hand is holding) not with our feet.

You might be able to say that an elephant *swatted* something with his tusk or trunk, or a yak swatted something with his head, but that would be a metaphorical stretch because a **swat** is a very quick directed motion involving *aim*, even if the aim is not precise.

Comment: I think the reason for using ***swat*** in the cited context is *specifically* because we often use it in respect of "trivial" annoyances such as flies. That's to say the implication is the Yak isn't meaningfully endangered by the addressees attacks. Which could equally have been conveyed by using something like ***brush aside*** to further accentuate how little the Yak is bothered by the attack, but using ***swat*** is simply a stylistic choice that places more emphasis on how ***forcefully*** it deflects the attack, even with little effort.

Comment: ...which is to say that although in some contexts (such as swatting at a cloud of midges) swatting them aside might be pretty futile, in the exact context that's not an issue. So as regards that business about ***swatting*** having allusions to ***attempting*** to deflect or drive something away, I'd say that aspect doesn't apply here.

Comment: I agree that it's being used because an aspect of the word involves a size ratio. That which can be **swatted aside** is usually much smaller than the swatter.

Comment: **swat *at*** *does* apply here because it addresses OP's question about which meaning was intended. I emphasize the preposition to indicate that that meaning does not apply here because **aside** was used, not **at**.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't notice that all-important ***at*** in your first sentence. Yes, I agree absolutely that ***to swat at*** something usually implies *failure* to drive it away (despite perhaps making quite vigorous efforts), but ***to swat aside*** almost always implies *success* (and little effort).