# What does "swat" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "swat" mean in a football (soccer) context?

> Thomas Tuchel’s unbeaten honeymoon continues as Chelsea confidently **swat** Everton aside at Stamford Bridge.

Comment: The same as it does in any other context. Have you looked up _swat aside_?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175087/swat-attack-aside

Answer (score 2):

Swat can mean:

**Hit or crush (something, especially an insect) with a sharp blow from a flat object.**

or

**Hit (someone) with a sharp blow.**

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/swat)

Even with its second meaning there is a sense of doing something trivial. We mostly swat mosquitos and flies. Your sentence means it was simple to beat Everton; it was *child's play*.